# How to inflate listview in fragmnet?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

im having a lot of trouble trying to inflate a layout with a custom listview into a fragment activity, I've searched every question about the topic in a lot of pages but i can´t find the problem, I´ll leave my code and the log cat of the error. Thanks a lot

Costum Adapter:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter   implements OnClickListener {

  /*********** Declare Used Variables *********/
   private  PlaceholderFragment  activity;
private android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment;
private ArrayList data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public Resources res;
ListModel tempValues=null;
int i=0;

/*************  CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
public CustomAdapter(PlaceholderFragment customListView, ArrayList d,Resources resLocal) {

       /********** Take passed values **********/
       activity = customListView;
       data=d;
       res = resLocal;

       /***********  Layout inflator to call external xml layout () ***********/
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )activity.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

/******** What is the size of Passed Arraylist Size ************/
public int getCount() {

   if(data.size()<=0)
       return 1;
   return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
   return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

/********* Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements *********/
public static class ViewHolder{

   public TextView text;
   public TextView text1;
   public TextView textWide;
   public ImageView image;

}

/****** Depends upon data size called for each row , Create each ListView row *****/
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   View vi = convertView;
   ViewHolder holder;

   if(convertView==null){

       /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
       vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null);

       /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

       holder = new ViewHolder();
       holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
       holder.text1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
       holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);

      /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
       vi.setTag( holder );
     }
   else 
       holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

   if(data.size()<=0)
   {
       holder.text.setText("No Data");

   }
   else
   {
       /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
       tempValues=null;
       tempValues = ( ListModel ) data.get( position );

       /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/

        holder.text.setText( tempValues.getCompanyName() );
        holder.text1.setText( tempValues.getUrl() );
         holder.image.setImageResource(
                     res.getIdentifier(
                     "com.androidexample.customlistview:drawable/"+tempValues.getImage()
                     ,null,null));

        /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row *******/

        vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener( position ));
   }
   return vi;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
       Log.v("CustomAdapter", "=====Row button clicked=====");
}

/********* Called when Item click in ListView ************/
private class OnItemClickListener  implements OnClickListener{           
   private int mPosition;

   OnItemClickListener(int position){
        mPosition = position;
   }

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {


       PlaceholderFragment sct = (PlaceholderFragment)activity;

    /****  Call  onItemClick Method inside CustomListViewAndroidExample Class ( See Below )****/

       sct.onItemClick(mPosition);
   }               
}
```

PlaceholderFragment (Fragment Activity):

```
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
/**
 * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
 * fragment.
 */
 ListView list;
 CustomAdapter adapter;
 public  PlaceholderFragment CustomListView = null;
 public  ArrayList<ListModel> CustomListViewValuesArr = new ArrayList<ListModel>();



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        CustomListView = this;
        setListData();

        Resources res =getResources();
        ListView list= ( ListView )view.findViewById( R.id.list1 );  // List defined in XML ( See Below )


        adapter=new CustomAdapter( CustomListView, CustomListViewValuesArr,res );
        list.setAdapter( adapter );
        return view;
}
     public void setListData()
     {

         for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {

             final ListModel sched = new ListModel();

               /******* Firstly take data in model object ******/
                sched.setCompanyName("Company "+i);
                sched.setImage("image"+i);
                sched.setUrl("http:\\www."+i+".com");

             /******** Take Model Object in ArrayList **********/
             CustomListViewValuesArr.add( sched );
         }

     }


    /*****************  This function used by adapter ****************/
     public void onItemClick(int mPosition)
     {

     }

     public static Activity getApplication() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    public LayoutInflater getSystemService(String layoutInflaterService) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


public PlaceholderFragment() {
}
```

Log cat (error):

```
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at        com.ipssum.demofood.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:77)
 01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):   at  android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15592)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:666)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15592)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825) 
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15592)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1451)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15592)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15592)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15592)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2180)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15592)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1878)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4356)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
01-13 14:43:48.229: E/AndroidRuntime(24059):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Firstly you are not adding your list view in fragment. Secondly which line is 77 in CustomAdapter.java?

Comment: You are getting a null pointer exception at line 77 in the getView function of your CustomAdapter. You should debug/step through line 77 and figure out what is null that you expect not to be null.